# Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе не цифр, выдавалось сообщение об ошибке, в python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть текстовое поле:

```
txt = Entry(window,width=15) 
txt.grid(column=1, row=0)  
txt.focus()
```

Как сделать чтобы если пользователь вводил не число, то выскакивало сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959815/restricting-the-value-in-tkinter-entry-widget

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class window:
    def __init__(self, master1):
        self.panel2 = tk.Frame(master1)
        self.panel2.grid()
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.panel2, text = "Quit", command = self.panel2.quit)
        self.button2.grid()
        vcmd = (master1.register(self.validate),
                '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')
        self.text1 = tk.Entry(self.panel2, validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd)
        self.text1.grid()
        self.text1.focus()

    def validate(self, action, index, value_if_allowed,
                       prior_value, text, validation_type, trigger_type, widget_name):
        if value_if_allowed:
            try:
                float(value_if_allowed)
                return 1
            except ValueError:
                messagebox.showerror("Title", "your error")
                return 0


        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Title", "your error")
            return 0


root1 = tk.Tk()
window(root1)
root1.mainloop()
```